# Prevent browser from starting more than 1 time

Tags: c#

```
    IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    public void InitChrome(IWebDriver e)
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        Driver =  driver;
    }

    public void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        InitChrome(Driver);
        string title = Driver.Title;
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///" + filename);
        Driver.Navigate().Refresh();
        InitChrome(Driver);
    }
```

Everytime I save a file when using this code, a new instance of Google Chrome starts, what can I do to prevent this while keeping this line `Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///" + filename);`?

Comment: Why do you call init twice?

Comment: It was a typo, removing one of them did not fix it

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you will need only one instance of `WebDriver`, and singleton pattern could help you with that.

```
public static IWebDriver _driver;

public IWebDriver Driver { 
    get {
        if(_driver == null)
        {  
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
            var _driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }
        return _driver;
    }
}

public void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///" + filename);
    Driver.Navigate().Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, what should the last line be changed to in your code? `InitChrome(Driver);`

Comment: Just remove it.

Comment: If I remove it and run the code, it says that Driver is empty in the second method

Comment: I don't see you use "title" anywhere so you could just also remove it.

Comment: I tried that as well but it still returns `System.NullReferenceException:`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding

```
    if (Driver == null )
    {
        InitChrome(Driver);
    }
```